# import local module in azureml endpoint

Tags: python, module, endpoint, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to create and endpoint for my azureml model. All the examples that I have seen for the moment use models from the library sklearn, so no problem to load the model from .pkl file.

In my case, my model is of a custom class that I wrote my self "bert_based_model".

The problem now is when compiling my score.py file, I get an error :

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bert_based_model'

How can I import my custom model in azureml endpoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a script **my_module.py** that contains your custom model class `MyBertModel`, you should place the script under the `source_directory` of the endpoint and import the class in the entry script.

So, if this is your inference configuration:

```py
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    environment=env,
    source_directory='./endpoint_source',
    entry_script="./score.py",
)
```

This is how **./endpoint_source/** should look like:

```
.
└── endpoint_source
    ├── score.py
    ├── my_module.py
    └── ...
```

And this is how your entry script `score.py` should look like:

```py
from my_module import MyBertModel

# other imports
...

def init():
    global model
    
    # load the model here, from pickle file or using the custom class
    model = ...
   

def run(data):
    # use the model here to predict on data
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure or upload such a my_module.py script in the Studio?